# How to use the mipmap folder in Xamarin.Android?

Tags: android, xamarin.android

For app icons we should use the `mipmap` folder. Now I added the following folders to the `Resources` folder:

- mipmap-hdpi
- mipmap-ldpi
- mipmap-mdpi
- mipmap-xhdpi
- mipmap-xxhdpi
- mipmap-xxxhdpi

In each of these folders there is a `ic_launcher.png` for the app icon and the build action is `AndroidResource`.

Now I can't set the `Application Icon` in the `Android Manifest`. It doesn't appear there. What I'm missing?

I deleted the default icon in the `drawable` folder and removed the entry in `Android Manifest`. On build I got

> No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/icon').
>   File: ...\SomeApp.Droid\obj\Debug\android\manifest\AndroidManifest.xml

There was an entry in `MainActivity` which was the old reference to `Icon = @drawable/icon`. Now I changed to `Icon = @mipmap/ic_launcher` and the error was gone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I manually edited the `AndroidManifest.xml` to use the `mipmap`folder:

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"></application>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Tried these:**

1. I deleted all references to default icon.
2. Deleted the icon in Drawable folder itself.
3. Added the new reference to my mipmaps (in Resources) in Manifest. 
   and still no resource match was found.

**Additionally:**

What I had to do was add the folders and icons in manually (i.e. `right-click > add > new folder`). I could not just drag and drop it in whereas doing so does not allow you to see the icon files inside folders either.

It seems the build action should automatically be set to newly added resources ([ref](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/resources_in_android/part_1_-_android_resource_basics/)). I'm not sure why a drag-and-drop to solution explorer would "hide" files in folders.

Comment: Reasons for down-votes would be appreciated here. This solution helped my so I'm sure it could help others as well.

Answer (score 1):

**No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@mipmap/CircleIcon')**

In my case my icon name is "*CircleIcon.png*".

I fixed this issue by doing the following:

1. Change name of the icon *CircleIcon.png* to *icon.png*.
2. Reference it again in the project.
3. Change `MainActivity` to this:

   ```
   [Activity(
        Label = "Appname",
        Icon = "@mipmap/icon",
        Theme = "@style/MainTheme" /*"@android:style/Theme.Material.Light" */,
        Exported = true,
        LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTask,
        MainLauncher = true,
        ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation,
        HardwareAccelerated = true,
        ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
   ```
4. Clean solution space and rebuild.